# How do I remove the subscript after calling BaseForm?

Tags: conversion, number-bases

Say I want to convert some number $N$ to base $k$.  Here, I might use the command `` BaseForm[N,`k] ``, e.g., `` BaseForm[10,`2] `` which gives the output $1010_2$ (where 2 is subscript).  How can I drop the subscript and manipulate the number as if it is a normal integer in decimal form?  I'd ideally like to do this without any string processing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `BaseForm[number,base]`

Use `IntegerDigits[number,base]` :

```
IntegerDigits[10, 2]

(* --->  {1, 0, 1, 0} *)
```

It returns a List of Integers, which is a very 
good thing for further processing

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is more than enough, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the format.  Thank you andre!  Mr. Wizard also :)

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
toBaseString[n_?NumericQ, b_Integer?Positive] :=
  First @ StringSplit @ ToString @ BaseForm[n, b]

toBaseString[365.7, 5]
```

> ```
> "2430.32222"
> ```

---

I missed that you didn't want strings.  Perhaps you want this?:

```
toBasePlain[n_?NumericQ, b_Integer] /; 11 > b > 0 :=
  N @ FromDigits @ RealDigits[n, b]

toBasePlain[365.7, 5] // InputForm
```

> ```
> 2430.322222222222`
> ```

Comment: It seems I was way off the mark but I'll leave this answer for anyone who finds this question through a search and may want something else.

Comment: Glad you kept the answer. I needed the `toBaseString` function that you wrote :)